# Are URLs (not domains) suitable for OpenID 2.0 identities?

Tags: openid, identity, delegation, openid-provider, indieweb

I have previously used OpenID 2.0 identities and delegation [1] in the context of [indieweb use-cases](https://indieweb.org/), where there is an assumption that each user controls a domain. So an identity would look like `https://example.com`

Can an OpenID 2.0 identity take the form of a URL, rather than just a domain? For example, both `https://example.com/alice` and `https://example.com/bob` would be:

1. valid, independent identities
2. could each delegate to a separate identity provider

[1] **Not** OpenID Connect, which does not support delegation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-supplied identifiers [must be normalized](https://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#normalization). If the input gets treated as HTTP(S) URL:

1. Use `http` if no scheme is specified
2. Strip off the fragment (including the `#`)
3. Follow redirects
4. Normalize the destination URL [according to RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6)

[Appendix A.1.](https://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#normalization_example) gives some normalization examples: the inputs `example.com` and `http://example.com` would become `http://example.com/`.

So an identifier can’t be just a domain, it *has* to be a URL. And there is no relevant difference between the URLs `https://example.com/` and `https://example.com/foo`. This means it’s perfectly fine to provide multiple identities under the same host/domain.